# Robot arm colliding with workcell

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having an issue in my robot cell where the robot is sitting on the edge of a table and the table is outlined by four posts. running the robot to a random location in the  center of the table I have about a 50 percent chance of the robot pathing through one of the posts close to it. [image: image description]

I've read through some of the moveit docs such as this http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/ompl_interface/ompl_interface_tutorial.html and I've tried to play with "longest _valid_segment_fraction" for my planner. I don't know that I've seen any changes though. I've also tried to make the collision tags for each of the posts slightly larger so the sample checker has a higher probability of checking in collision but that hasn't helped either.

I guess my first question is how exactly do I use the "longest _valid_segment_fraction". my assumption was to place it inside the specific motion planner headder like the following.

```
  RRTConnect:
    type: geometric::RRTConnect
    range: 0.0  # Max motion added to tree.
    longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.0005
```

are there any other ways of preventing the collisions?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328138/robot-arm-colliding-with-workcell/) by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-10**:
I've closed your question as it violates the Support Guidelines. Specifically the request to *not* post screenshots of code/terminals or other kinds of text.

The RViz screenshot is fine, but please replace the screenshot of the `.yaml` file.

Copy-paste the contents into your question, select all of it and then press the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it).

You don't need to post a new question: just use the `edit` button/link to edit it.

**Comment by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on 2019-07-10**:
I fixed it but cant reopen it myself.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-10**:\

> I guess my first question is how exactly do I use the "longest _valid_segment_fraction"

I would first check your collision geometry.

Does your cell have proper collision geometry specified?

Can you show a screenshot of RViz with the collision geometry enabled?

**Comment by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) on 2019-07-10**:
You were right, I forgot that I set an artificial ceiling so I didnt need to make collision objects for the upper rails. in the initial pose the robot was already in collision with the ceiling. I made the top rails like I should have done from the start and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would first check your collision
> geometry.
>
> Does your cell have proper collision
> geometry specified?
>
> Can you show a screenshot of RViz with
> the collision geometry enabled?

This from gvdhoorn was the correct answer to my problem. Thanks

---

Originally posted by [pathare](https://answers.ros.org/users/40445/pathare/) with karma: 28 on 2019-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0